# how do i remove results where I am getting a duplicate in 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

This is my first question asked on this site.
Hopefully I get it right :-)
I have searched for similar questions but all I can find is how to remove duplicate results where the entire line is the same
I have tried DISTINCT and GROUP BY but neither produces what I want.

My code is:

```
SELECT
[ID-HNO-3] AS number,
[ST-STS-61] AS modality
FROM
[RENALPLUS].[dbo].[tbl_Change_of_Status]
WHERE
[ST-STS-61] = 'akc'
OR
[ST-STS-61] = 'neph op'
GROUP BY
[ID-HNO-3], [ST-STS-61]
ORDER BY
[number] ASC
```

This produces results along the lines of:

```
column 1 | column2
__________________
1        | neph op
2        | neph op
3        | neph op
4        | neph op
5        | neph op
6        | neph op
6        | AKC
7        | neph op
8        | neph op
9        | neph op
10       | neph op
```

The expected result is:

```
column 1 | column2
__________________
1        | neph op
2        | neph op
3        | neph op
4        | neph op
5        | neph op
6        | AKC
7        | neph op
8        | neph op
9        | neph op
10       | neph op
```

Neither column is a key.

Each result also has a date associated with it and each date is unique but not a key

you will see that column 1 has 6 duplicated.

When this is the case, I need to just return 6 once where 6 has the most recent date

Can someone explain how to do this as I seem to be unable to find out how it's done

Thank you for your help.

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result as well!

Comment: @3rdRockSoftware . . . Because of the syntax, I assume this is SQL Server, so I added the tag.  For future questions, please add the database you are using.

Comment: @jarlh I have edited the post. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT [ID-HNO-3] AS number, [ST-STS-61] AS modality
FROM (SELECT cos.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID-HNO-3] ORDER BY date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [RENALPLUS].[dbo].[tbl_Change_of_Status] cos
      WHERE [ST-STS-61] IN ('akc', 'neph op')
     ) cos
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY [number] ASC
```